# Save result in excel cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

datas1 = [{'A':10, 'B':100}, {'A':11,'B':-210}, {'A':12,'B':120}, {'A':14, 'B':30}]
datas2 = [{'A':25, 'B':90}, {'A':11,'B':-50}, {'A':110,'B':(-15)}, {'A':5, 'B':65}]
datas3 = [{'A':5, 'B':-100}, {'A':19,'B':210}, {'A':12,'B':-300}, {'A':14, 'B':30}]

for i in [datas1, datas2, datas3]:

    df = pd.DataFrame(i)
    df['CUMSUM'] = (df['B'].cumsum())

    if (df['CUMSUM'] < -100).any():      
        print(df.loc[df['CUMSUM'] < -100, :].head(1))
        print ("")  
    else:       
        print(df.loc[df['CUMSUM'] >= -100, :].tail(1))
        print ("")
```

Output:

```
    A    B  CUMSUM
1  11 -210    -110

   A   B  CUMSUM
3  5  65      90

    A    B  CUMSUM
2  12 -300    -190
```

How can I get each CUMSUM result into different cells of an Excel Sheet?
I mean:

-110 in cell A1

90 in cell A2

-190 in cell A3

... and go on ...

Comment: Have you had a look into `xlsxwriter` module already? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter/

Comment: Yes, I´ve done it. The problem is that I don´t know how to save each result value in ["CUMSUM"] to different cells, each time I run the program with different datas strings (data1, data2, data3, etc)

Comment: What does that mean? Post your code. If you use the *same* cell address each time you'll overwrite the existing values. You can refer to columns by index and increase the row index for each iteration. You can write an entire row at a time with write_row

Comment: Do you want to append rows to an existing spreadsheet? Then you would need to iterate over the rows until you find the first one that's empty. Enter your CUMSUM at these coordinates. `sht.write(row_index, col_index, CUMSUM)`